# What is the most efficient way to search in date ranges in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I'd like to ask what is the most efficient (and fastest) way to search for data between 2 dates?

Let's consider having following simple query:

```
SELECT Date_,counter1,counter2,...
WHERE (date range condition)
```

The "Date_" column is a DATETIME type.

I tried different options like:

```
WHERE Date_ >= '2012-12-01 00:00:00' AND Date_ <= '2012-12-05 00:00:00'
```

and

```
WHERE Date_ BETWEEN '2012-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-05 00:00:00'
```

and

```
WHERE Date_ = '2012-12-01 00:00:00' OR Date_ = '2012-12-02 00:00:00' OR
Date_ = '2012-12-03 00:00:00' OR Date_ = '2012-12-04 00:00:00' OR
Date_ = '2012-12-05 00:00:00'
```

In fact this Select query is a lot more complicated (with joins and more conditions). This is only the simplified version. According to EXPLAIN there is no difference, how the query is executed. I need to say that Date_ column is indexed. Unfortunately, I cannot test the real query speed, because I cannot avoid OS caching, but at least MySQL cache was not used (SQL_NO_CACHE).

**Is there according to your experince a faster way to search in date intervals (without functions)?**

**Which of the three methods is faster (in case that there is a difference at all)?**

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you forgot `where date_ in ('2012-12-01', '2012-12-02', etc...)`. technically there shouldn't be any difference in performance for the `where or or or or` and `where in` versions. they'd both be parsed/executed the same internally.

Comment: Hard to back up with facts other than testing, but as a general rule of thumb when the plan is the same - less to parse, less wasted CPU. A prepared statement with two parameters (of one of the two first examples) should prove even faster.

Comment: query 1 and 3 or 2 and 3 are not equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The big factor in efficiency is going to be the availability of suitable indexes, and the generation of an efficient execution plan.

Our normative pattern for searching a datetime range is to use a greater than and equal to, and a less than (but not equal to) comparisons.

To get all datetimes for a single day, for example, '2012-12-01', we typically code this like:

```
WHERE datetimecol >= '2012-12-01'
  AND datetimecol <  '2012-12-02'
```

-or-

```
WHERE datetimecol >= '2012-12-01'
  AND datetimecol <  '2012-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Similarly, to get the five day range in your example:

```
WHERE datetimecol >= '2012-12-01'
  AND datetimecol <  '2012-12-06'
```

-or-

```
WHERE datetimecol >= '2012-12-01'
  AND datetimecol <  '2012-12-01' + INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

---

To answer your question, "is there a faster way?"  No. A predicate of that form enables MySQL to perform a range scan on an index (given a suitable index available.)  It doesn't get any more efficient than that.

Comment: Thanks, spencer! The experince that I have with MySQL (not big) and all the forums that I examined, showed to me that the biggest factor is indeed the correct indexing. In fact the full query, in which this date interval search is done is posted here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458367/correct-indexing-by-join-where-group-by-select-queries-avoiding-using-temporary). Unfortunately, I didn't receive any answers, but I will re-post the question in a different form, something like: "What indexing would you use in the explained situation".